# How to Authorize my App and Auto Access my E-mail account without asking a user authentication?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-client

I have E-mails in my g-mail account that I wish my App to access without my authorization as an user.

I managed to connect via OAuth 2.0, but that's not quite what I need. I would like my app to be linked with my E-mail automatically.

And thus, any user that access my App will have access to my E-mail (thought the App), is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The key is to create a service account and then implement G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation. [Link](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) This method is the official supported method.

Another method, ***that is less secure***, is to authenticate with User Credentials. Store the Client ID, Client Secret and OAuth 2 Refresh Token. You application then creates a new Access Token and uses that for authorization. This [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) shows how to do this in Python.

Think thru what you are trying to accomplish and more importantly the security risks associated with each method.